# Upload images on background mode

Tags: ios, background, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

I have  web service which i want to use to upload image to the server, web service proxy classes generated by wsdl2objc it uses NSOperation to perform soap calls. Suppose during the upload process i press the home button and application enters the background mode, what will be in that case? will the upload process terminate? or process will complete anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the OS will freeze your app in the background. When that happens, the remote server will probably close the connection after a while because your app doesn't respond.

You can avoid that by wrapping your upload code in a background task (with the methods `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` and `endBackgroundTask:`), in which case the OS will let your app run in the background for another 10 minutes to finish its work.

Comment: is it possible to have more than one background task ?

Comment: Yes, you can have as many as you like. `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` returns an identifier that you have to store and then pass to `endBackgroundTask:` to pair the two calls. But no matter how many background tasks you have, the OS will not give you more than 10 minutes of time.